# Default file type in tkFileDialog's askopenfilename method

Tags: python, tkinter

For some reason, the default file type changes depending on whether I open the file dialog with the menu, or withe the Ctrl+O hotkey.
Why?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

FILEOPENOPTIONS = dict(defaultextension='.bin',
                       filetypes=[('Bin file','*.bin'), ('All files','*.*')])

class TestGUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('Test')
        menu = self.menubar = Menu(self)
        fmenu = self.filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', underline=0, menu=fmenu)
        fmenu.add_command(label="Open", underline=0,
                          accelerator='Ctrl+O',
                          command=self.fopendialog)
        self.config(menu=menu)
        self.bind_all('<Control-o>', self.fopendialog)

    def fopendialog(self, event=None):
        print repr(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=self,
                                                **FILEOPENOPTIONS))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = TestGUI()
    test.mainloop()
```

Comment: What OS are you on? And in what way does the menu change?

Comment: Windows 7, the default selected file type changes depending on which method is used to open the file dialog. That's it. In one case it will be "All files", and in the other it will be "Bin file" - both are available in the dropdown menu, it's just a matter of which is default.

Comment: Try a different version of Python? This forum [post](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/tkFileDialog-askopenfilenames-returns-unicode-string-instead-of-tuple-in-python-2-62-td1978109.html) points out another bug with tkFileDialog in Python 2.4 and/or Python 2.6. Have you tried Python 2.7 or even 3.2?

Comment: Well, I'm running 2.7, but I haven't tried it in 3.2 since I haven't migrated to 3.X yet. I guess I'll try it in 3.2

Comment: is that possible that I can able to browse the files of remote machine through `askopenfilename` or other command

Comment: For windows it works for shares as in: `\\some_remote_computer\shared\folder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem, but I fixed it by putting the default file extension last in the dictionary.

Like this:

```
FILEOPENOPTIONS = dict(defaultextension='.bin',
                  filetypes=[('All files','*.*'), ('Bin file','*.bin')])
```

See the example on [this page](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) for reference.

Comment: Just as additional info: this is not documented thing, so it might change depending on OS/version.
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkFileDialog.html